# Managing APK pointing to staging server & production via Google Beta Testing

Tags: android, testing, beta

What's the best practice for managing testing with an APK pointing to staging & production via the Google Play Store Beta Testing platform?

Do you usually have a completely separate application listing w/ the build that points to staging, and if so how would you handle the different signing-certs?

Or do you manage everything via the Alpha & Beta channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't usually use Google Play Beta, but often change staging/production/development situations with Gradle.

write your app gradle like this below.

configurations

```
configurations {
    stagingDebugCompile
    stagingReleaseCompile

    productionDebugCompile
    productionReleaseCompile

    developmentDebugCompile
    developmentReleaseCompile
}
```

signing config

```
signingConfigs {
    def releaseSettingGradleFile = new File("${project.rootDir}/release.gradle")
    if (releaseSettingGradleFile.exists()) {
        apply from: releaseSettingGradleFile, to: android
    } else {
        release {
            def debugSettingGradleFile = new File("${project.rootDir}/debug.gradle")
            apply from: debugSettingGradleFile, to: android
        }
    }

    def debugSettingGradleFile = new File("${project.rootDir}/debug.gradle")
    debug {
        apply from: debugSettingGradleFile, to: android
    }
}
```

build types

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

product flavor

```
productFlavors {
    staging {
    }
    production {
    }
    development {
    }
}
```

Don't forget put the release.gradle and debug.gradle file.
debug.gradle could be like this.

```
signingConfigs {                                                                                                                                              
    debug {
        def HOME = System.getProperty("user.home")
        storeFile file("${HOME}/.android/debug.keystore")
        storePassword "android"
        keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
        keyPassword "android"
    }
}
```